# proof of gauge invariance for quantum 1D ring

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gauge-theory

This is a question on gauge invariance in quantum mechanics.  I do some simple math on a 1D wave-function with periodic boundary conditions, and get that gauge invariance is violated.  What am I doing wrong?

Consider one coordinate dimension configured as a ring. The gauge dependent momentum operator can be written:

$p_{op}=-i \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - k$

Units have been chosen so that $\hbar = 1$, $k$ is an arbitrary real constant different for each gauge and $x$ represents the coordinate.

The gauge dependent eigenfunction can be written

$\psi(x)= Ae^{i(n+k)x}$

where A is a constant determined by normalization.  As is well known in quantum mechanics, an operator applied to one of its eigenfunctions should yield a real constant eigenvalue multiplying the same eigenfunction:  Thus

$[-i \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - k]  Ae^{i(n+k)x}= nAe^{i(n+k)x}$

so that the real number n is the eigenvalue, which must be determined by the boundary conditions.

The boundary condition for this periodic system must be that the wave function should join onto itself smoothly everywhere.  Thus, if the coordinate is chosen such that x extends from –$\pi$ around the ring to $\pi$ then the eigenfunction in equation 3 must have (n + k) = m, where m is an integer.

Under these conditions, the eigenvalue n in equation 3 will be n = m – k.  This eigenvalue depends explicitly on k, and so is not gauge invariant.

I'm assuming this simple situation should be gauge invariant, but I don't see where I goofed.  I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Thanks to kmm for upgrading the format of my equations.--AD

Comment: @Arthur Davidson: You're welcome.

Comment: You didn't goof up. You just discovered that von Neumann theorem doesn't need to hold for non-trivial systems. Recall than for systems on ${\mathbb R}^N$ (described by Heisenberg group) von Neumann states that all strongly continous unitary irreducible representations of the Heisenberg group are equivalent and you can always work in the standard representation given by multiplication and derivation operators for $x$ and $p$. This **doesn't** hold for topologically non-trivial manifolds (such as circle) and there is continuum of inequivalent irreducible representations (index by $k$ here)!

Comment: The same thing (although more complex) happens in QFT where there is a problem with a choice of vacuum. Again, this is because QFT can be realized as a system with infinite number of degrees of freedom, so $N \to \infty$ and von Neumann doesn't hold again.

Comment: @Arthur: the kinds of edits you've been making (at least, I assume it's you and not someone pretending to be you) are what comments are for. You'll need to log in to leave comments. If you're no longer able to log in to the account you posted this question under, just create a new account and I can merge them for you. (Use the "flag" link under the question to bring it to my attention)

Comment: @Marek: Thanks for thinking about my problem.  So you're saying that because Von Neumann's theorem (which I don't recognize) needn't hold for quantum mechanics on a ring, therefore gauge invariance also need not hold?

Comment: @Arthur sorry for being imprecise, the full name is: [Stone - von Neumann theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%2dvon_Neumann_theorem) -- check it out. And no, it's not because of this theorem but rather because of its failure. In other words, for strange things like this to happen one needs the theorem *not* to hold in the given setting but it is not yet a sufficient condition.

Comment: @Marek: Thanks for the additional info.  So I think you're saying that the lack of gauge invariance is not a math mistake, but is a reflection of a deeper issue: namely the commutation of Q  and P was not formulated to account for physics on a ring?

Comment: @Marek: By the way, why don't you elevate your comment to an answer--I'd like to give you credit for a "useful answer."

Comment: @Arthur: I don't really have an answer. I just wanted to bring into your attention the fact that this stuff is actually pretty deep. Well, at least from the mathematical point of view, physicists don't really care usually and proceed in the standard fashion. And usually they get the correct results. I always wondered how they do that... :)

Comment: @Arthur, @Marek: I'm so confused. Why is this not just because the quantity being calculated is simply not gauge invariant? i.e. it is not physical. BebopButUnsteady's answer below translates the problem into a magnetic problem, in which the answer is known, and the answer is indeed that the "momentum" being calculated is simply not physical?

Comment: @genneth: @Marek: The momentum state of the ring is so simple, with no force or field applied, that the momentum eigenvalue has to be a real physical value, which means it should not depend on an _arbitrary_ choice of gauge.  So if it does, there has to be a physics or math error somewhere.  Marek suggested the Stone-von Neumann theorem as a possible math problem.  I wonder if the usual periodic boundary conditions themselves, could be the problem.

Comment: @Arthur: but you explicitly construct a gauge dependent quantity?

Comment: @genneth:By definition the momentum operator and eigenfunction are each gauge dependent.  But the theory is that the resulting eigenvalue, which is what is measurable, should be gauge independent, or gauge invariant.  At least that is the theory I'm going by.

Comment: @genneth: @Marek: @Qmechanic:@BebopButUnsteady:I posted a 5 page paper showing how nonlinear boundary conditions return gauge invariance to the quantum 1D ring.  Here is the link: [Nonlinear Boundaries in Quantum mechanics](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4510)

Comment: @Arthur: but it is simply false that eigenvalues have to be gauge invariant. In fact, we define a gauge invariant operator to be one which has invariant eigenvalues! You state that it is measurable, but give no justification for it. You seem to be confusing the statement "measurable quantities in quantum mechanics are eigenvalues of Hermitian operators" with its converse --- not all operators give physically measurable quantities.

Comment: @genneth: My understanding is that gauge invariance of eigenvalues is an axiom of quantum mechanics.  It's ultimate justification is experiment.  Operators and wave-functions need not be gauge invariant because they are unmeasurable parts of the theory.

Comment: @Arthur: then I'm afraid your understanding is wrong. The axioms of quantum mechanics make no reference to gauge invariance, and reality of eigenvalues is not a given.

Comment: @genneth (sorry for the late reply). What we have here is *not* gauge transformation. This is simply a shift in the momentum, i.e. a boost. When you perform it also in classical physics you will find that both momentum and kinetic energy changes, i.e. they are not "gauge" invariant (to use your terms). When on circle, the transformation gives you an observer that revolves with different speed. But the mathematically interesting fact is that whereas the linear case gives the same physics, the circular one doesn't (for topological reasons).

Comment: @Marek: that is what I was trying to get at for the OP. He seems to have co-opted the term "gauge invariance" where it does not apply at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to try an answer for my own question.

The straightforward interpretation of the 3 equations in the original post is that they do present a legitimate conflict.  This conflict disappears when the spatial domain is extended to infinity, and the role of the boundary conditions goes away.  So, the conflict, the violation of gauge invariance for the finite ring, suggests that either the ring is simply not covered by quantum mechanics, or there is something about the boundary conditions implied by the ring geometry that doesn't work.

So are there other boundary conditions that could be tried?  The obvious ones are to demand periodicity not of the wave function, but of the probability density and probability current density.  These are both real (not complex) quantities, would let the phase of the wave function have a discontinuity at the boundary, so long as the gradient of the phase was smooth.

Such a choice for the boundaries would allow the continuous eigenvalue spectrum of the infinite line to apply as well to the ring, which would restore gauge invariance.  But this comes at the expense of inhomogeneous and nonlinear boundary conditions.

The nonlinear boundary conditions could be accepted if they are consistent with the standard type of Hilbert space of Hermitean operators, and the principle of superposition.

In a paper I recently posted on arxiv.org I go into some detail about how the nonlinear boundaries are indeed consistent with both gauge invariance and the standard structure of Hilbert space.  The bottom line is that the nonlinearity creates a continuous spectrum of eigenvalues, not all of which are superposable in Hilbert space.  The nonlinearity in the boundary allows a subset to be superposable.  The combination of continuous eigenvalues and superposable discreet eigenvalues makes a band structure for the Hilbert space, rather than simple discreet levels.

[PLEASE CLICK HERE for the larger explanation.](http://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all%3a+AND+boundaries+AND+davidson+nonlinear/0/1/0/all/0/1)

So I think the correct solution of this problem is quite significant for quantum systems coupled to their environments, such as Josephson junctions used as qubits.

Answer (score 4):

### **2nd Update**

If you just want to think about a 1D universe with periodic boundary conditions, there is simply the point that there is no gauge transformation that takes from one you value of $A$ constant to another. Recall a gauge transformation takes $A_\mu\rightarrow A_\mu +\partial_\mu f$, where $f$ is an arbitrary *smooth*  function. To go from $A = A_1$ to $A=A_2$ you would want to gauge transform with $f(x) = (A_1-A_2)x$. But since your system is periodic in $x$ this is not a smooth function. That would be okay if $\exp(i f(x)$ was a single valued function but that only happens when $A_1 -A_2$ is an integer. It is an interesting fact about some topologically nontrivial spacetimes that there are gauge fields which give the same electromagnetic fields but are not equivalent by gauge transformation. And Quantum Mechanics actually cares about the gauge fields. So it does not break gauge invariance for different $A$ to give different physical answers, since they are not connected by a gauge transformation.

The update below is mainly concerned with thinking about your 1D quantum ring as embedded in actual space. Still worth reading

### **Update**

Arthur, I applaud the fact you're still attempting to understand this. So I'm trying to re-explain what I wrote here. QMechanic and Marek have both provided good explanations, but they don't hit exactly the source of what seems to be your confusion. Let me try again to explain.

-Your question is: I have this simple system with a gauge field, and my answer seems to be depend on my choice of gauge. How can this be? I thought nothing physical can depend on your choice of gauge.

- Let's step back and remember where we first met gauge invariance. We had these $E$ and $B$, the electromagnetic fields, and these are observable physical quantities. But these are a pain to work with so we introduce the gauge fields $A$. But these are massively redundant - I can gauge transform my fields $A$ to something completely different and still have the same $E$ and $B$.  Since $E$ and $B$ are what we care about in the first place we demand our theories be "gauge invariant" - nothing physical can change when I do a gauge transformation.
- Gauge invariance is created by the fact that different gauge fields lead to **physically equivalent** situations. There are lots of things that look like gauge fields - but only in those situations where gauge transformation connect **physically equivalent** situations  must gauge invariance be respected.
- In the situations you mention yourself, the rigid rotator, there is something that looks a lot like a gauge field. We have a hamiltonian $H = \frac{1}{2m}(p - m\omega R)^2$, where $\omega$ is the angular velocity. This looks just like a gauge field $A= m\omega R$. But different values of $A$ and $\omega$ do **not** correspond to the same physical situation. The rotator is spinning at a different speed. This is visibly different. Because the different $A$ are physically inequivalent, there is no reason to expect the answer to be independent of the value of $A$. And thats what you find. Correctly.
- In the case where $A$ actually is the electromagnetic vector potential the situation is slightly more subtle, since thats really supposed to gauge invariant. But I show below in the original post that, here as well, different choices of $A$ correspond to different physical situations.

**Bottom Line:** Just because something looks like a gauge field doesn't mean we must have gauge invariance. Gauge invariance is only a must when gauge transformations connect **physically equivalent** situations. In the systems that realize a 1D quantum ring different choices of $A$ are not physically equivalent.

### **Original Post**

Your original calculation is correct. The energy levels do depend on the magnitude of the gauge vector $A$.

How does this not break gauge invariance? Calculate $\oint A(r)\cdot dr$, that is the integral of your gauge field around the loop. This is $\int dS\cdot \nabla \times A$ by Stokes theorem. This is $\int dA \cdot B$ by the  definition of the gauge field. So its equal to the magnetic flux $\Phi$ threading through your ring.

So if you take $A$ to be constant like you did, then we have $A = \frac{\Phi}{2\pi R}$, where $R$ is the radius of your ring. But $\Phi$ is a physical quantity -  it can't change under gauge transformations. There is no gauge transformation that keeps $A$ constant and changes its magnitude.  So its okay that different $A$ give different energy levels - they correspond to different physical situations.

This is the basis for many physical phenomena: the Aharanov-Bohm effect, flux quantization, Little-Parks effect, weak localization etc.. It's all on wikipedia.

By the way, the weird part here is not so much that your answer depends on the guage, since the different gauges are not equivalent. The weird part is that if I take a ring a light year in radius and put a magnetic field through the a meter-squared patch in the center of the ring, all the particles know about this magnetic field even though they are a light year away. But if I cut a meter long chunk out of my ring they suddenly forget all about that magnetic field.  (Only in the limit where everything is impossibly clean, but still, its wacky).

Comment: I appreciate your intuitive approach, but I think it is misleading.  The problem I posed has no potential.  I am considering a rotator without torque or applied field of any kind.  The question is, where in my 3 equations and continuous boundary condition is the error that produces a violation of gauge invariance?

Comment: @Arthur Davidson: I apologize for leaping to the magnetic field language. You didn't actually specify what the gauge field was, so I assumed. But the point remains: If two gauge fields give the same physical configuration than no physical quantity can distiguish them. But the point is although normally adding a constant to the gauge field gives the same physical, with non-trivial boundary conditions this gives a _different_ physical configuration. In the rotator case adding a constant to the gauge corresponds to spinning faster, which is a physically different situation. So there is no reason

Comment: -cont-- for the energy levels to be the same and indeed they aren't. If you want the more general and more mathematical statement, than see Marek's comment.

Comment: Comment to the answer (v3): In the periodic 1D space, the Lie-algebra-valued gauge-parameter called $f(x)\in u(1)$ does not have to be single-valued. Only the Lie-group-valued gauge-element $e^{if(x)}\in U(1)$ and the derivative $\partial_x f(x)$ must be single-valued. This implies that $A_x$ is actually allowed to change with a discrete amount under a so-called 'large' gauge transformation, i.e. a gauge transformation not continuously connected to the identity.

Comment: @Qmechanic: Thank you for the clarification. I did not know whether people allowed transformations not connected to the identity or just accepted extra degeneracy. I will update it to reflect your comment.

Comment: @BebopButUnsteady: I think your phrase "So it does not break gauge invariance for different A to give different physical answers, since they are not connected by a gauge transformation" is the crux of the problem.  First, I think  you and I agree that different A's seem to give different physical answers.  So what I don't get is the statement that different A's are not connected by a gauge transformation.  In my view, in the simple ring and only considering the momentum operator, each choice of A is a valid gauge, and should lead to an eigenvalue independent of gauge.

Comment: @BebopButUnsteady: Also, it is obvious that my third equation in the original post has a gauge invariant eigenvalue,n, independent of k, just as I have been saying, for the case where x goes off to infinity--where the boundary conditions are usually assumed to be that the wave-function amplitude goes to zero.

Comment: @Arthur Davidson: Let's see... Forget about 1D for a second, think about gauge fields in 3D.  I can write down a Hamiltonian with a gauge field equal to any function, $\vec{A} = \vec{f}(\vec{x})$. And my energy levels are going to depend on which $\vec{f}(\vec{x})$ I choose. Does this violate gauge invariance? No! Gauge invariance only requires that if there exists a gauge transformation that takes gauge $A_1$ to gauge $A_2$, then $A_1$ and $A_2$ have to give the same physical answers. It doesnt require that all choices of functions for the gauge fields have to give the same answer - cont -

Comment: Okay now come back to 1D. It is a fact of 1D with trivial boundary conditions, that all functions $f(x)$ are equivalent to each other by gauge transformation. But now when I put on periodic boundary conditions this is no longer true! Thats what QMechanic and I have shown in our answers. There is no gauge transformation that takes you from, say, $A=0$ to $A=1/2$. Because there is no gauge transformation that connects the two, gauge invariance doesn't require that they give the same answers, and they don't.

Comment: @BebopButUnsteady: OK! But when you pick that function f(x), you have to add its space integral to the wave-function phase, and it's time derivative to the potential energy, and then you're back at the original eigenvalue equation, and the energy eigenvalues should not change.  The wave function depends on the gauge, and the operator depends on the gauge, but the energy eigenvalue does not depend on the gauge. I posed my question relative to the momentum operator rather than the Hamiltonian for simplicity and clarity.

Comment: @Arthur Davidson: I dont know which $f(x)$ in my comment you're referring to when you say "add its space integral to the wave-function phase". If you mean in 1D with p.b.c., you can't "add its space integral" because that's not a single valued function. If you take the integral around the whole circle you don't get $2\pi n$ in general. If you mean in 3D, then "its space integral" is not well defined since it depends on the path you take the integral. In either case, only when the two gauges differ by a gauge transformation is what you say well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

1) Let us for simplicity put various constants to one: Speed of light $c=1$; Planck constant $\hbar=1$; Mass  $m=1$ of non-relativistic scalar (Bosonic) particle in $1+1$ dimensions; charge of particle $q=1$; Circumference of spatial circle $\ell=2\pi$.

2) The mechanical momentum (sometimes called the [kinetic momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_momentum))

$$\hat{v}~=~\hat{p}-A_x~=~\frac{1}{i}\partial_x-A_x~=~\frac{1}{i}D_x$$

(or equivalently, the covariant derivative) commutes with the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}=\frac{1}{2}\hat{v}^2+\Phi$ in the temporal gauge $\Phi=A^t=0$, which we will assume from now on. (Recall that $\Phi=A^t$ is the temporal component of the gauge potential.)  So we can find common eigenstates. Suppressing the time dependence in what follows, we want to solve the mechanical momentum eigenvalue equation

$$\hat{v}\psi_v(x)=v \psi_v(x),$$

where the mechanical momentum eigenvalue $v\in\mathbb{R}$ is related to the energy
$E=\frac{1}{2}v^2$. The solution is $e^{ivx}$ times a Wilson line:

$$\psi_v(x)~=~ \psi_v(0)\exp\left[ivx+i\int_0^x A_x(x')dx'\right] ,\qquad v\in\mathbb{R}.$$

3) Under a local gauge transformation

$$\psi(x)\longrightarrow \tilde{\psi}(x):=e^{i\alpha(x)}\psi(x), \qquad A_x(x)\longrightarrow \tilde{A}_x(x):=A_x(x)+\partial_x\alpha(x), $$

it is well-known that the [covariant derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_covariant_derivative) (or mechanical momentum) transforms covariantly,

$$D_x\psi(x)\longrightarrow e^{i\alpha(x)}D_x\psi(x), \qquad 
D_x \longrightarrow \tilde{D}_x ~=~ e^{i\alpha(x)}D_x e^{-i\alpha(x)}, 
\qquad \hat{v}\longrightarrow e^{i\alpha(x)}\hat{v} e^{-i\alpha(x)}.$$

It is true that they are not gauge invariant. They are only gauge covariant. However, we may easily construct manifestly gauge invariant quantities, for instance,  $|\psi(x)|^2$; $\psi^*(x) \hat{v}\psi(x)$. In particular, the mechanical momentum eigenvalue

$$v~=~\frac{\hat{v}\psi_v(x)}{\psi_v(x)}~=~\pm\sqrt{2E}~\in~\mathbb{R}$$

is a gauge invariant (still assuming temporal gauge $A^t=0$).

4) Finally, we assume for simplicity that $A_x(x)=A_x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\tilde{A}_x(x)=\tilde{A}_x\in\mathbb{R}$ are independent of $x$. This corresponds to a partial gauge fixing. We still have residual gauge transformations left where $\alpha(x)$ is an affine function of $x$. The eigenfunction becomes

$$\psi_v(x)~=~ \psi_v(0)e^{i(v+A_x)x},\qquad
\tilde{\psi}_v(x)~=~ \tilde{\psi}_v(0)e^{i(v+\tilde{A}_x)x},\qquad v\in\mathbb{R}. $$

We now recall that the $x$-coordinate is periodic $x\sim x +2\pi$. The wave function should be single-valued

$$\psi_v(x+2\pi)=\psi_v(x),\qquad\tilde{\psi}_v(x+2\pi)=\tilde{\psi}_v(x),$$

so

$$v+A_x,v+\tilde{A}_x~\in~\mathbb{Z},$$

as OP observes. In other words, $A_x$ and $\tilde{A}_x$ belong to the same shifted lattice $\mathbb{Z}-v$. The residual affine function $\alpha(x)$ must have $x$-independent integer-valued derivative

$$\partial_x\alpha~=~\tilde{A}_x-A_x~=~(v+\tilde{A}_x)-(v+A_x)~\in~\mathbb{Z}.$$

5) So what have we learned?

1. On one hand, we may write $v\in\mathbb{Z}-A_x$, so we see that the energy $E=\frac{1}{2}v^2$ and the mechanical momentum $v$ *depend on the gauge* potential $A_x\in\mathbb{R}$.
2. On the other hand, we saw in section 3 that $E$ and $v$ *are gauge invariants,* i.e., they are invariant under gauge transformations (still assuming temporal gauge $A^t=0$).

The two statements (1.) and (2.) do not clash in terms of physics, only in terms of semantics. In particular, if we perform a gauge transformation on the formula $v\in\mathbb{Z}-A_x$, we cannot claim that $v$ changes since a gauge transformation changes $A_x$ by an integer. ($A_x$ itself is not necessarily an integer.)

6) Another example is the canonical momentum operator $\hat{p}=\frac{1}{i}\partial_x$.

1. On one hand, it is *independent of the gauge* potential $A_x$.
2. On the other hand, it is *not a gauge covariant quantity,* i.e., it does not transform covariantly under a gauge transformation

$$\hat{p}\longrightarrow  e^{i\alpha(x)}\hat{p} e^{-i\alpha(x)}~=~\hat{p}-\partial_x\alpha(x).$$

Again, the two statements (1.) and (2.) do not clash in terms of physics, only in terms of semantics.

7) Finally, let us connect to Marek's comment. We have a Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ of wave functions on a circle $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, and a Heisenberg algebra $[\hat{x},\hat{v}]=i$. (More precisely, the [Stone-von Neumann theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem) is a statement about the corresponding [Heisenberg group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) to avoid issues with [unbounded operators.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator)) I interpret Marek's comment as roughly saying that

$$\hat{x}=x, \qquad \hat{v}=\frac{1}{i}\partial_x-A_x,$$

yields inequivalent irreducible representations of the Heisenberg algebra labeled by a continuous label $A_x\in[0,1[$. Changing $A_x \to A_x+1$ yields an equivalent representation due to gauge symmetry.

Comment: @Qmechanic: I think I follow most of you math, except for "residuial affine function," but I think in the end you get the same non gauge invariant eigenvalue that I do.  Do you not have the eigenvalue v, which is real, and v+Ax must be an integer?

Comment: @Arthur Davidson: I added some more explanation to the answer (v2).

Comment: @Qmechanic: Thanks for adding more info.  Your bottom line (literally) is "This implies that the wave function ψ˜v(x)=ψv(x) is actually gauge invariant under the remaining affine gauge transformations."  Doesn't this mean that gauge invariance of the momentum eigenvalue is valid only if we restrict Ax to integers?

Comment: @Arthur Davidson: I removed the incorrect bottom line in v3.

Comment: @Qmechanic: So would you say that your analysis leads to the same flawed conclusion as mine?

Comment: @Qmechanic: But I thought gauge invariance applies to any gauge. That is why gauge invariance is so powerful in physics. You're not allowed to say "well, it doesn't work for this gauge, so don't worry about it, just use that gauge." The choice of gauge variable should be arbitrary. Why does it work only for integer Ax in this case?

Comment: @Qmechanic: Let me ask you another question: have you looked at the comments from Marek and my responses?  He (or she) seems to think that the lack of gauge invariance is not a math mistake at all, but arises from deeper issues in quantum mechanics.  What do you think of Marek's comments?

Comment: @Qmechanic and @Marek: Thanks for you thoughts and efforts.  But I still go with Marek in the comments that my math is OK, and there **is**  non-gauge invariance here, which reflects a problem of some kind deeper in quantum mechanics, if not in the Stone-von Neumann theorem.

Comment: Your persistence in getting this right is appreciated.  But in regard to your revised #6 above, could it not be argued that your canonical momentum operator pˆ=-i∂x is not independent of Ax.  This form, I think, requires the choice of gauge such that Ax=0.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're seeing a problem where there isn't one. Indeed we have $n + k \in \mathbb{Z},$ so if you shift $k$, say $$k \mapsto k + \delta,$$ you need to adjust $$n \mapsto n - \delta.$$ I wouldn't say that $n$ explicitly depends on $k$, but shifting $k$ by an arbitrary *real* (= non-integer) constant does force an adjustment for $n$ - not very surprising.

However, I think you can set up the problem in a more natural way. Forget about the gauge part, just consider the wave function $\phi(x) = e^{i n x}$; to satisfy the p.b.c., you find that $n \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Now add a gauge part, $U_k(x) = e^{ikx};$ you then find that the derivative changes to $\partial_x \mapsto D_x = \partial_x - ik$ (modulo a sign error) etc. The total wave function changes to $\phi(x) \mapsto U_k(x) \phi(x) = \Psi(x)$; again, you find that $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ etc.

In this new set-up, you find that you can change $k$ by an integer without punishment, and I think this is also meant in your problem; once you restrict yourself to the integers, you have integer freedom in your choice of gauge.

Comment: I don't understand "you find that $k \in {\mathbb Z}$". How did you find that? I am curious because this statement *doesn't* hold ;)

Comment: If n is integer, and n + k is integer, than k is also integer - right? Please explain what's going on!

Comment: In that case I have no idea what's this answer supposed to mean because in the original problem there *was* the freedom to choose arbitrary real $k$.

Comment: I think I see the gist of your answer.  But I don't have a theoretical physics or advanced math background: can you go step by step, and use English instead of logic symbols to show how your solution gives gauge invariance?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do quantum mechanics on other domains than $\mathbb R^3$, but you have to make a few adjustments, which you forgot to do. Namely, the gauge transformation

$$ \psi(x) \mapsto e^{i\chi(x)} \psi(x) $$

must fulfill $e^{i\chi(0)}=e^{i\chi(2\pi)}$ to be single-valued on the circle, i.e.

$$\chi(2\pi)-\chi(0)=2\pi m \quad\text{ with } m\in\mathbb Z$$

In other words, your choice $\chi(x)=kx$ is only allowed for particular values of $k$, namely $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Moreover, the eigenvalue does not depend on the gauge, despite your claim to the contrary. That's because a gauge transformation will *change the velocity operator*

$$ v \mapsto v - \partial_x \chi(x) $$

and its eigenvalues stay the same. No physically measurable quantity will change after a gauge transformation, ever.

Comment: I agree that gauge invariance works with periodic boundary conditions on the ring for integer values of k.  My point is that gauge invariance will work for real values of k if you're willing to change the boundary conditions.  Moreover, making the probability density and probability current density periodic instead of  the raw wave function seem like perfectly reasonable things to do.  My arxiv.org paper goes into the details: http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4510   .  By the way, I expanded this paper and the revision should show up 8/1/2011.

Comment: @Arthur Davidson: It's ok to change the boundary conditions of the wave function (to $\psi(2\pi)=e^{i\theta}\psi(0)$). But the gauge transformation must *still* fulfill periodic boundary conditions.

Comment: _@Greg Graviton:I don't believe there is anything in gauge theory that says the ring domain can only have integer gauges.  Rather, that is the only thing that works if periodicity is required of ψ.  Putting the boundary condition on the periodicity of ψ*ψ relieves the necessity of using only integer gauge variables, so ultimately, the question can only be settled by observation.

Comment: @Arthur Davidson: Nope. The gauge transformation shouldn't change the vector bundle, i.e. the boundary condition. This means that it has to be periodic. (Unlike $\psi(x)$, which doesn't need to be periodic.)

Comment: _@Greg Graviton: I need an explanation or reference about your assertion about "the vector bundle." It would be good if there were an explanation aimed at an advanced undergrad physics major.

Comment: @Arthur Davidson: "Sections of vector bundles" are the right generalization of wave functions on domains other than $\mathbb R^3$. You may want to have a look at the article ["On the theory of identical particles"](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~cabrera/teaching/referencia.pdf) by Leinaas and Myrheim. While it's not a direct exposition on the issue of vector bundles and wave functions, it's a beautiful paper and makes good use of these "generalized wave functions".

Comment: _@Greg Graviton: Thanks for the reference.  I was especially interested to see Leinaas & Myrheim use the prob. current density as a boundary condition in their Eq. 15, though they linearized it in Eq. 16. I don't know if that changes any of their results.  As you said, there is not much directly applicable to my Stackexchange question on gauge invariance.  So I'm sticking with my own answer here.  As a side note, my extended draft on arxiv has now been updated with an explicit momentum matrix operator with a nonlinear boundary condition.   [Link to arxiv.org](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4510)